# Convert X and Y px base on Screen size

Tags: android, math, screen

im using this command `input tap x y` (`input tap 600 500`) in a phone with a screen resolution of `720 x 1280` how do I convert the `x y` so it will be same point in a phone with a resolution of `1080 x 1920`. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pseudo code should get you the values you're looking for:

```
resolution_width = 720;
resolution_height = 1280;

input_x = 600;
input_y = 500;

target_width = 1080;
target_height = 1920;

percent_width = input_x / resolution_width;
percent_height = input_y / resolution_height;

output_x = target_width * percent_width;
output_y = target_height * percent_height;
```