# Coordinate X& Y on Screen different size

Tags: android, size, coordinates

I have a view and inside a viewpager with images. When I touch the view I display an image where I'm touching.
In the same time I send X and Y position in Firebase.
In another device, I get back those coordinates and display an image at those coordinates.

But the screen size of the tablets are differents, how can I show my image at the same position ? Because if I touch the middle screen of the first tablet, it showing an image en the right bottom of the other one

**UPDATE**

For user 1, when he touch the view a pointer/cursor is showing

```
 v.animate()
 .x(Math.round(event.getX()))
 .y(Math.round(event.getY()))
 .setDuration(0)
 .start();
```

In the same time he sends coordinates to Firebase and the width and height of his screen.

```
    Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
         Point size = new Point();
         display.getSize(size);
         int width = size.x;
         int height = size.y;

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("x", Math.round(event.getX()));
        map.put("y", Math.round(event.getY()));
        map.put("sizeX", width);
        map.put("sizeY", height);
        mRefMyPos.updateChildren(map);
```

The user 2 has a listener and get back those data to display an imageView at the coordinates.

```
 listenerRefCoordonate = mRefCoordonate.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            CoordonateModel coordinateModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(CoordonateModel.class);

            if (coordinateModel == null){
                //do something
                mImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {

                final Float mScale = Math.min(1.0f * width / coordinateModel.getSizeX(), 1.0f * height / coordinateModel.getSizeY());

                if (coordinateModel.getX() != null){
                    mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mImageView.animate()
                            .x(Math.round(coordinateModel.getX() * mScale))
                            .y(Math.round(coordinateModel.getY() * mScale))
                            .setDuration(0)
                            .start();
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {
        }
    });
```

Seems to be incorrect for example if I have an imageview with ABCDEFGHI.... (match_parent), if I try to show C, it showing E on the other device. Maybe my scale is incorrect ??

I tried to test if the scale is correct. When I touch the screen without displaying imageview where I'm touching but I'm listening what I'm writting on FireBase and displaying imageview with coordinates/with and height of screen device and do the scale and the when I'm displaying the imageview it showing where I'm touching so I guess the scale is correct

I will try to re explain my problem:

Tablet n1, 1024/768
Tablet n2, 1920/1200

Both are on a view full_screen with the same Imageview scale FitXY and match_parent
On the first tablet I'm touching the tail of the pig (Imageview), I'm sending X,Y position of the screen touch (Math.round(event.getX(), Math.round(event.getY()) and the width/height screen size of the tablet. The second tablet displaying (a cursor) around the tail of the pig but not at the exact position....

Can someone help me ?

User tablet 1 touching his screen (RED POINT where he's touching)
[image: User tablet 1 touching his screen (RED POINT where he's touching)]

User tablet 2 listening X,Y position and draw where the user 1 is touching (RED POINT)

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

I changed and I calculate like this one on this post stackoverflow.com/a/21588683/5845928 I have what you said : tablet 1 the point is (258,230) and tablet 2 (484, 359). the problem seems to be the imageview. How can I solve it ?

** FIXED **

TABLET 2 receive x,y position and width and height of tablet 1.

```
hisWidth = coordinateModel.getSizeX();
hisHeight = coordinateModel.getSizeY();

float percent_width = Float.valueOf(coordinateModel.getX()) / hisWidth;
float percent_height = Float.valueOf(coordinateModel.getY()) / hisHeight;
float x = percent_width * mWidth;
float y = percent_height * mHeight;
```

Comment: Try sending relative positions. In example, if you're touching middle of the screen, send 0.5, 0.5 as coordinates. Then on another device re-calculate those to match the middle of that screen.

Comment: any luck in finding the solution? i m facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to send also device width and height, so you could use them to calculate the exact (X,Y) in other devices

Comment: I updated my code and send width and height of the device. Then I calculate
                    final Float mScale = Math.min(1.0f * width / coordinateModel.getSizeX(), 1.0f * height / coordinateModel.getSizeY());

But still displaying to the wrong place. I have an imageview in match_parent/match_parent on both devices, the problem can come from here ?

Comment: how do you calculate your new (x,y) point in new device? Let's say that in tablet 1 the point is (258,230), in tablet 2 the point should be (484, 359). Could you verify this as first? If this is correct, then the problem is in your imageview that is rendered with different size in tablet 2

Comment: I changed and I calculate like this one on this post
http://stackoverflow.com/a/21588683/5845928

I have what you said : tablet 1 the point is (258,230) and tablet 2  (484, 359).
the problem seems to be the imageview. How can I solve it ?

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117932/how-to-get-same-co-ordinates-for-image-for-all-resolutions-in-android